# How do I iterate through a string array in Power Query?

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have this function in Power Query (because CELL("filename") doesn't work with OneDrive Excel Files):

```
let
    Source = (sFilename as text) => let
        Source =   
        try
            Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\Will\Data Sources\" & sFilename), null, true)
        otherwise try 
            Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\Dave\Data Sources\" & sFilename), null, true)      
        otherwise try 
            Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\Esmeralda\Data Sources\" & sFilename), null, true)
    in
        Source
in
    Source
```

Works fine.

Would you please help me re-write it so that it loads rows (with C:\Users\Will\Data Sources\ etc. as the values) from a table in Excel, and iterates through those rows in the same fashion above.

That way rather than editing the Function to hard code another file path, I can just add another file path to the table in an Excel sheet.

Thanks

CELL("filename") will return the sharepoint URL and not the local file folder when using an Excel file on OneDrive for business.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this: set up a range name, containing paths

[image]

Then in PowerQuery, use code to check those locations for filename, in a procedure

```
let Source="xxxxxxxxxxxx",

retrieve = (check as text) as table=>
    let filelist = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="NameList"]}[Content],
    #"Check All" = Table.AddColumn(filelist, "Custom", each Excel.Workbook(File.Contents([Column1]&check))),
    #"Removed Bad" = Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors(#"Check All", {"Custom"})
    in #"Removed Bad"{0}[Custom],

getfile= retrieve("oooo.xlsx")

in getfile
```